# Laravel: Retrieve the one-and-only record from database

Tags: singleton, laravel-6

How can I retrieve the one-and-only record from the database w/o `Model::all();`?

I do not know it's `id` either so I can't use `Model::find($id);`.

Comment: [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) - ```$flight = App\Flight::where('number', 'FR 900')->first();```

Comment: I need to know a way even w/o `first()`? I just need to retrieve the one-and-only record. If there is no 'proper' way to get this done, I would use a where clause along with `first()` which will return the only record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `first()` method to get the first record from the database matching additional conditions if any are included:

```
$record = Model::first();
```

This will return an instance of `Model`, or `null` if there are no records present.

Comment: I never thought I can use `first()` w/o a `where`. Will try this and make this the answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: You definitely can :) `first()` is just a shorthand for `limit 1` in SQL, so it's basically the same as `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1`, which will return the first (and in your case only) record from the table. Also, if you have a Laravel project, you can type in the console `php artisan tinker`, followed by `User::first()` (or whatever Model) to see the result.